# How to tell which version of a package was tagged for a particular release?

Tags: ros, installation, source, rosinstall, build-from-source

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm trying to determine which version of joystick_drivers was tagged for electric. I could brush up on my svn foo and sniff around the repository, but I figure there must be a list somewhere which I haven't been able to find. Bonus points if you can then point me to the tarball for that release.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35923/how-to-tell-which-version-of-a-package-was-tagged-for-a-particular-release?/) by [AndrewStraw](https://answers.ros.org/users/203/andrewstraw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 171 on 2012-06-07

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For each stack on the wiki they have a subpage Releases which lists the released versions.  For example see the [geometry/Releases page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/geometry/Releases).  This is linked to in the stack header.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-06-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-06-07**:
According to http://www.ros.org/wiki/joystick_drivers/Releases, the corresponding SVN tag is https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/joystick_drivers/tags/electric/

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-06-07**:
If you really want the tarball, it is here: https://code.ros.org/svn/release/download/stacks/joystick_drivers/joystick_drivers-1.6.4/joystick_drivers-1.6.4.tar.bz2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I usually open synaptic package manager (if you're not on ubuntu this won't be helpful) and enter the driver name. It will have a "ros-[releasename]-joystick-drivers"

I feel like the name of the release should be added to the xml of a package for any developers reading this, but if you are just using svn I would try to compile it. If it doesn't work, use the `rosmake --rosdep-install` If it still doesn't work, then I would just look elsewhere.

Sorry if I'm not being very helpful... What distro are you running?

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2012-06-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1